# Change the button label on 'file' upload

Tags: symfony

How to change the button label for 'upload'

I am making upload form like this.

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder($document)
 ->add('file',null,array('label' => 'send'))
```

it makes a button labeled 'upload documents'

I want to change label to 'send'

How can I change the label of button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do one more add like:

```
->add('send', 'submit')
```

altogether:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($document)
 ->add('file')
 ->add('send', 'submit')
```

If you would rather it be a regular button and not a submit button you could do this.

```
->add('send', 'button')
```

**Edit**

Symfony 2.3.+  is required.

Comment: I tried both '->add('send','button')' and  '->add('send','submit')',but it says 'Could not load type "button(or submit)"'

Comment: Update your symfony version to 2.3.x. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/button.html